# ANDROID FirebaseDatabase: Unable to save object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Couldn't add an object to firebase realtime database. I tried the following code. But when this code executes

```
db.child("Users").setValue(person);
```

my app crashes

```
public class Person{
   String fname;
   String lname;
   Person()
   {}
   Person(String fname,String lname)
   {
       this.fname = fname;
       this.lname = lname;
   }

   public String getFname() {
       return fname;
   }

   public String getLname() {
       return lname;
   }
}
```

Here is the ERROR.

> 11-20 15:34:57.762 2752-2752/shazdroid.com.surveyapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: shazdroid.com.surveyapp, PID: 2752
>                                                                          com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting
>   getters for name: isChangingConfigurations
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy$zza.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzca(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzch(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy$zza.zzci(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzca(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzbz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                              at shazdroid.com.surveyapp.AddMember.savePerson(AddMember.java:207)
>                                                                              at shazdroid.com.surveyapp.AddMember.access$000(AddMember.java:37)
>                                                                              at shazdroid.com.surveyapp.AddMember$6.onClick(AddMember.java:193)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Here is how i'm saving the object.

```
    private void savePerson() {
    suc.show();
    Person person = new Person("shahbaz","ansari");
    db.child("User").setValue(person)
            .addOnCompleteListener(AddMember.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                suc.dismissWithAnimation();
                suc = new SweetAlertDialog(AddMember.this,SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                suc.setTitleText("Successful");
                suc.setContentText("Saving data successful");
                suc.setConfirmText("OK");
                suc.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                    }
                }).show();
            }else{
                suc.dismissWithAnimation();
                suc = new SweetAlertDialog(AddMember.this,SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
                suc.setTitleText("Failed");
                suc.setContentText("Failed to save data");
                suc.setConfirmText("Try Again");
                suc.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        savePerson();

                    }
                });
                suc.setCancelText("cancle");
                suc.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The stack trace refers to `isChangingConfigurations`, which is the name of a method of `Activity`.  This probably indicates that you have declared class `Person` as an inner class of an activity.  When Firebase serializes `Person` it also tries to serialize the enclosing Activity class and fails.

Move the declaration of `Person` to package level or change the declaration to make it a static inner class: `public static class Person`.

Comment: And how could i save bunch of info of a single person like, Name,Age,ID, etc... including the date of saving the data so that i retrieve data of single person according to given date?